# react jest test return error when test component with properties

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer

I would like to know why my last test is failed -> it("cron input should have a passed Value in properties".
I tried to test my react component without and with properties,
the first two test pass but the last one give me an error.
it's like my component doest take the values of the attributes I passed.

this is the output error for test :

```
● Stl Cron component › cron input should have a passed Value in properties

expect(element).toHaveValue(0 * * ? * * *0 0/15 8-17 ? * MON-FRI *)

Expected the element to have value:
  0 * * ? * * *0 0/15 8-17 ? * MON-FRI *
Received:
  0 * * ? * * *0

  22 |     render(<StlCron value={"0 * * ? * * *0 0/15 8-17 ? * MON-FRI *"} />);
  23 |     const stlCronInput = screen.getByTestId("stlCronInput");
> 24 |     expect(stlCronInput).toHaveValue("0 * * ? * * *0 0/15 8-17 ? * MON-FRI *");
     |                          ^
  25 |   });
  26 | });
  27 |
```

this my react component :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { Divider, Input } from "antd";
import { ReCron, Tab } from "@sbzen/re-cron";
import "./StlCron.scss";

const StlCron = ({ value, onChangeHandle, tabs }) => {
const [cronValue, setCronValue] = useState(value ? value : "0 0 0 ? * * *");

return (
    <div className="Stl-cron">
      {<Input data-testid="stlCronInput" value={cronValue} />}
      <Divider />
      <ReCron
        renderYearsFrom={new Date().getFullYear()}
        renderYearsTo={new Date().getFullYear() + 10}
        value={cronValue}
        onChange={(value) => {
          onChangeHandle(value);
        setCronValue(value);
        }}
        tabs={tabs}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

StlCron.propTypes = {
  tabs: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
  onChangeHandle: PropTypes.func,
};

StlCron.defaultProps = {
  tabs: [Tab.SECONDS, Tab.MINUTES, Tab.HOURS, Tab.DAY, Tab.MONTH, Tab.YEAR],
  onChangeHandle: () => {},
};

export default StlCron;
```

and this is my test file.

```
import { cleanup, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import StlCron from "./StlCron";

afterEach(() => {
// cleanup();
});

describe("Stl Cron component", () => {
  it("should render stlCron component", () => {
      //screen.debug();
      render(<StlCron />);
      const stlComponent = screen.getByTestId("stlCronInput");
      expect(stlComponent).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it("cron input should have default Value when init", () => {
      render(<StlCron />);
      const stlCronInput = screen.getByTestId("stlCronInput");
      expect(stlCronInput).toHaveValue("0 0 0 ? * * *");
  });

  it("cron input should have a passed Value in properties", () => {
      render(<StlCron value={"0 * * ? * * *0 0/15 8-17 ? * MON-FRI *"} />);
      const stlCronInput = screen.getByTestId("stlCronInput");
      expect(stlCronInput).toHaveValue("0 * * ? * * *0 0/15 8-17 ? * MON-FRI *");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but I normally use `toHaveAttribute`.

```js
expect(stlCronInput).toHaveAttribute("value", "0 * * ? * * *0 0/15 8-17 ? * MON-FRI *");
```